# Java program to call static method from main

Tags: java, oop

I got confused for this java program . Can anybody please tell me what will be the output of this program?

```
class Sample {

    public static void start() {
        System.out.println("Bla bla...");
    }

    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        try {
            start();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Java compiler and JVM can tell you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because you're asking us to be your Java compiler and JVM for you.

Comment: Why do you need try/catch statements for that? :-)

Comment: You could tell us why you find it confusing, rather than asking us to read your mind... Odds are good that you're getting unexpected output simply because you aren't running what you think you're running (forgot to compile after your last change, for example).

Comment: did you run it ?? Run and see what comes.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is:

```
Bla bla...
```

<sub>There's not many times that "bla bla" is the *correct* Answer, so I'm just going to take the opportunity :-)</sub>

---

But just to add some value, I will point out that this:

```
    try {
        start();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
```

... is **absolutely terrible code**.  You are catching all possible exceptions ... and ignoring them.  If there was some bug in `start` that caused it to terminate unexpectedly, *you would never know why it happened*.  BAD.

Comment: Thanks stephen..actually i was told to tell the output of this program in interview. I had some confusion in calling that static method

Answer (score 1):

`main` gets called first, and then you call `start()` from `main`. In `start`, you print to the console 
`Bla bla...`

The `try-catch` block just ensures that if there are any [Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) that the `catch` part can handle what happens when an Exception is triggered. In your case, it would be *any* Exception.

---

Output:

```
Bla bla...
```

Comment: Thanks mike..actually i was told to tell the output of this program in interview.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm that is it possible to call static method from main like this ...